# How can I make my menu not break in mobile?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm using Bootstrap 4 to create my responsive site, and I'm using its responsive Navbar component based on this [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors). The navbar works fine in desktop but in mobile it breaks and I can't figure out why.

This is what's happening:
[image]

This is what I need:
[image]

My code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg nl-navbar navbar-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="#" alt="Logo" class="col-lg-7 col-md-6 
        col-sm-5 col-5"/>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
    target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto nl-navbar-ul">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link mr-3" href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link mr-4" href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link mr-4" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <button class="btn my-2 my-sm-0 nl-btn-nav-secondary" type="button" data- 
        toggle="modal" data-target="#" 
        id="#">Btn Here</button>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:right` property on `class="navbar-toggler"` and apply `display:block` propert on `nav` tag